# Chrome download bar causing view port to shrink and doesn't properly resize to normal when download bar is closed

Tags: javascript, browser, web

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for any help you can provide.  I have a web page that does a simple file download via a link.  In Chrome this causes the download bar to appear on the bottom of the browser.  However, when closing the download bar using the X on the right there is just white space left in the place where the download bar was displayed and the web page does not return to it's normal display.  Has anyone run into this before, and if so were you able to resolve it?  Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Does this happen when you shrink the browser window vertically from the bottom (similar to what download bar does)? If so it may not be exactly a Chrome bug.

Comment: I did try that but shrinking and expanding the browser vertically doesn't cause the issue.  However, I did notice that if I open developer tools, choose a div on the page that has a height, remove the height and then just reapply that same height to the same div, the empty space created by the download bar goes away.  I assume this is causing the browser to redraw.

Comment: That's a great discovery. Now let's hope that someone knows what this is related to.